# MySQL join tables for counts with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a report across 3 tables - company, account, user.  For each company, there's an ID in account.  Each user has an account.  I can get totals easily enough, but I need to add count of how many users out of the total are registered (username is not null).

```
SELECT c.c_name, c.c_groupnumber, count(a.a_userid) AS TotalCount
FROM company c
LEFT JOIN account a ON c.c_groupnumber = a.a_groupnumber
WHERE a.a_deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY c.c_groupnumber
HAVING TotalCount > 0;
```

How can I add in a condition that gives me a count of user.u_username not null while maintaining my TotalCount?  The link between account and user is

```
a.a_userid = user.u_userid

tbl.company
c_id, c_groupnumber, c_name
  1    1234          widgets, inc.
  2    5678          joe's garage

tbl.user
u_userid, u_username, u_name
  1        bill       Bill Smith
  2        frank      Frank Johnson
  3        NULL       Jane Doe
  4        mary       Mary Stack
  5        NULL       Steve Spot

tbl.account
a_id, a_userid, a_groupnumber
 100       1      1234
 101       2      5678
 102       3      5678
 103       4      1234
 104       5      1234
```

So using the above very simplified table example, company "Widget's Inc." has 3 employees (bill smith, mary stack and steve spot), and of those 3 2 have registered (bill and mary), while steve has not (username is null).

Joe's Garage has 2 employees - Frank and Jane, and Frank has registered, while Jane has not.

I'd love to generate a report something like this:

```
Group      Company     Total Emp      Reg Emp
1234       Widgets Inc     3              2
5678       Joe's Garag     2              1
```

Hopefully that makes the question clearer?

Answer (score 0):

What if you get the count of username and then perform a `JOIN` with that like

```
SELECT c.c_name, c.c_groupnumber, count(a.a_userid) AS TotalCount,
xxx.username_count
FROM company c
LEFT JOIN account a ON c.c_groupnumber = a.a_groupnumber
LEFT JOIN ( select u_userid, count(u_username) username_count
            from `user`
            group by u_userid ) xxx ON a.a_userid = xxx.u_userid
WHERE a.a_deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY c.c_groupnumber
HAVING TotalCount > 0;
```

Comment: It's only giving me a record username_count of 1.  I also added a where on the subquery (where u_username is not null) but it's still only giving a count of 1.  If there are 400 people (TotalCount) in the company, there will be 400 user accounts, but there may only be 300 with a username, so I'm trying to show both that total 400 and then the 300 count of those that have registered

Comment: The problem to me looks to be in the main select (SELECT c.c_name, c.c_groupnumber, count(a.a_userid)) - since c_groupnumber is the group by, I'm not actually getting all of the user IDs (a.a_userid) from the account table - I'm only getting a count.  I need to get the full list of a.a_userid to join to the user table a.a_userid = u.u_userid so I can add a where clause there to get a count with non-null usernames.

Comment: @Steve, can you post your table data along with expected output. am not quite getting your question here.

Comment: I've added some simplified sample data to 3 tables showing how they are connected